# Existe alguma forma de separar esse arquivo e chamar por ids

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, bootstrap-3

Galera bom dia estou elaborando um programa de enquete em php,preciso separar os id de uma pergunta, exemplo pegar o id da 1º pergunta e relacionar com a segunda.
Exemplo 1º pergunta Como vc avalia o atendimento se for otimo,bom,regular Ok finaliza, se for Ruim e péssimo vá para segunda pergunta Por que avalia essa opção:Tempo de espera,Mal atendimento, Outros. Porém as 2 perguntas tem que ter o mesmo ID.

```html
<?php

include_once 'conecta_bd.php';

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
 


 $enquete_id = $_GET['id'];
 $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT valor_opcao FROM opcao2 WHERE opcao_id = 1 AND enquete_id ='$enquete_id' ");
 $query->execute();
 $valores_opcoes = $query->fetchAll();


 $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT nome_enquete, descricao FROM enquete WHERE enquete_id ='$enquete_id' ");
 $query->execute();
 $query = $query->fetch();
 $titulo_enquete    = $query['nome_enquete'];
 $descricao_enquete = $query['descricao']; /* VER DEPOIS COM CALMA COMO SEPARAR ISSO EM OUTRO ARQUIVO VER TEST1.PHP E TEST2.PHP*/

 echo '<h1>'.$titulo_enquete.'</h1>

 <form action="checa_data.php" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">';
 
 for ($i=0; $i < count($valores_opcoes); $i++) { 
  
  $valor_opcao = $valores_opcoes[$i]['valor_opcao'];
  echo'<input type="submit" name="valor_opcao" value="'.$valor_opcao.'">'.$valor_opcao.'
  <br>';
 }

 echo'<input type="hidden" name="enquete_id" value="'.$enquete_id.'">
   <input type="submit" value="Votar!">
   </form>
  
  <h3>breve descrição:<h4>'.$descricao_enquete.'</h4></h3>
  <h3><a href="enquete_info.php?id='.$enquete_id.'">ver informações da enquete</a></h3><h3><a href="main.php">voltar à página inicial</a></h3>';

}



else
 header("location: main.php");

?>

<!--<script type="text/javascript">
   setTimeout(function $btnruim() {
            window.location.href = "index.html";
        }, 5000);

</script>-->
```

```html
<?php 
 /* Função para criar nova enquete, talves tenha necessidade de melhorar o
 código :| */

include_once 'conecta_bd.php';


if( !empty($_POST['titulo_enquete']) && !empty($_POST['descricao_enquete']) && !empty($_POST['data']) && !empty($_POST['opcao'])){
 
 $titulo_enquete  = $_POST['titulo_enquete'];
 $descricao_enquete = $_POST['descricao_enquete'];
 $data_enquete  = $_POST['data']; 
 $qtdade_opcoes   = $_POST['numero'];
 $opcoes       = $_POST['opcao'];

 $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO  enquete (nome_enquete, data_termino, descricao) VALUES ('$titulo_enquete','$data_enquete','$descricao_enquete') ");
 $query->execute();

 $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT max(enquete_id) FROM enquete");
 $query->execute();
 $id = $query->fetch();

 for ($i=0; $i<$qtdade_opcoes ; $i++) { 
  
  $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO  opcao (enquete_id,valor_opcao,numero_votos) VALUES ('$id[0]','$opcoes[$i]','0') ");
  $query->execute();
 }

 header("location: sucesso_enquete_criacao.php?titulo=$titulo_enquete&id=$id[0]");
}

 /* Valida enquete de pergutas 1 Recepçao e condição de botão RUIM e PÉSSIMO 
 para segunda pergunta */

if(isset($_GET['valor_opcao'])){
 
 $valor_opcao  = utf8_decode($_GET['valor_opcao']);
 $enquete_id   = $_GET['enquete_id'];
 

$query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE opcao SET numero_votos = numero_votos + 1 WHERE enquete_id ='$enquete_id' AND valor_opcao LIKE '$valor_opcao' ");
 $query->execute();

if($enquete_id == 1 ){

 if($_GET['valor_opcao'] == 'ÓTIMO' or $_GET['valor_opcao'] == 'BOM' or $_GET['valor_opcao'] == 'REGULAR'){

 header("location: sucesso.php?id=$enquete_id&valor=$valor_opcao");
                  
    }else{
      header("location: enquete1_2.php");
    }
}

if($opcao2 == 2 ){

 if($_GET['valor_opcao'] == 'TEMPO DE ESPERA' or $_GET['valor_opcao'] == 'EDUCAÇÃO DO PROFISSIONAL' or $_GET['valor_opcao'] == 'ESTRUTURA RUIM' or $_GET['valor_opcao'] == 'FALTA DE SERViÇO' or $_GET['valor_opcao'] == 'OUTROS'){

 header("location: sucesso.php?id=$enquete_id&valor=$valor_opcao");
                  
    }
}
                
}

else
 header("location: main.php");
?>
```

Comment: O que eu faria é uma requisição em Ajax que pega a resposta do primeiro formulário, e receba a resposta pelo servidor que devolve para o ajax, que compõe o texto da segunda pergunta

Comment: Blz vou verificar essa forma.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Cara posso muito bem estar errado, sou novo aqui no stack e estou enferrujado com php.
Mas pensando lógicamente, primeiro vc deve trocar esse if por um switch, onde vc pegue a resposta e apartir dela saia um resultado.
Não entendi pq as perguntas precisam de Ids, você poderia criar uma estrutura simples do texto da pergunta onde vc só mude as variaveis.
No caso como vejo, vc só precisa guardar o resultado da enquete.
Para a segunda opção, vc só precisaria mostrar o segundo texto dada as condições atendidas.
Se não entendi direito manda um feedback da minha resposta pf.

Comment: Entendi talvez seria isso também vou verificar é que quando eu falo id me refiro a uma unica pergunta, porém com opções de requezitos exemplo só vai para segunda pergunta se o usuário clicar em ruim ou péssimo, mas preciso separar isso de forma automática sei que manual é possível mas não o ideal.

Comment: então, essa separação pode ser bem simples da foma q falei, faz um switch, onde se a resposta for positiva guarda o nivel de satisfação, caso não for, vc retorna um modal ou uma nova page com o novo questionário.

Comment: Não acho uma boa guardar a estrutura da pergunta no DB, ainda mais se tratando de uma pergunta que serviria a outros usuários, como disse antes, crie a estrutura e apenas guarde as respostas, vai ficar um código mais limpo e eficiente.

Comment: Entendi obrigado